# Cannot implicity convert type object to system.data.datatable

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Hi I'm trying to do the following but it throws the error title. As I can fix?
Thanks!!!

```
public static object conectar(string query)
{
    DataTable Tabla = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = BaseDatos1.getConexion();
    SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
    Da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
    Da.FillSchema(Tabla, SchemaType.Source);
    Da.FillLoadOption = LoadOption.PreserveChanges;
    Da.Fill(Tabla);
    BaseDatos1.closeConnection();
    return Tabla;
}

public static string Verificar()
{
    bool functionReturnValue ;
    DataTable Dt1;
    DataTable Dt2;
    DataTable Dt3;
    int j;
    int k;
    int DigitoVerificador;
    int Acum;
    string A;
    string tablas = "";
    string[] table = new string[6];
    string registro = "";
    bool errorEnTablaActual;
    int reg = 0;
    try {
        functionReturnValue = true;
        //Verifico en Base Seguridad
        **Dt1 = conectar("select Tabla from DigitoVerificador");**
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because the `conectar` method returns an object, which you then assign to `Dt1`, which is a DataTable, and so you get the message that the value cannot be implicitly converted..

You can explicitly cast the return value to a DataTable, as the `conectar` method never returns null:

```
Dt1 = (DataTable)conectar("select Tabla from DigitoVerificador");
```

Alternatively, and probably better, you would change the return type of `conectar` to `DataTable`.